# how to add a image with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i use the following code for a sticky sidebar:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  

var stickWidth = jQuery(".sticky-sbar ul li a").width()+32;
var stickyBar = jQuery(".sticky-sbar").width()+ 37 -stickWidth;
jQuery(".sticky-sbar").css('right' , -stickyBar);
jQuery(".sticky-sbar ul li a#see-me").toggle(
function(){
    jQuery(".sticky-sbar").animate({"right": 0});
    //jQuery("a#see-me").css({"font-size":"16px","width":"30px"});
    jQuery("a#see-me").text('X');
    jQuery("a#see-me").css({"width":"45px"});
},
function(){
    jQuery(".sticky-sbar").animate({"right": -stickyBar});
    jQuery("a#see-me").text('More Products');

    jQuery("a#see-me").css({"width":"90px"});   
}
);

});
```

Now i want to add a image after the textfield "More Products". Is this possible?  Is it also possible to define a class for the text "More Products" ?

i hope somebody can help me.

best regards

edit html:

```
<div class="sticky-sbar" style="right: -250px;">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="see-me"><img src="/image" alt="More Products"></br></br> 
<p style="font-size: 16px;">More Products?</p></a><span>You will find more 
Products on</br><b><span style="font-size:18px"><a href="domain" 
target="_blank">domain.de</a></b></span></style><br/><br/></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post relevant html code also, this will help us to understand the issue and provide solution

Comment: and where will this image come from? is it a tag already exist on the page?

Comment: the image comes from a normal path? What you mean?